# Error installing VLC on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, yum, vlc

I'm trying to install VLC on Fedora 20, but I'm getting the following error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-5.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-5.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libgcrypt.so.20()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.4.2-1.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-5.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.1.5-5.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-5.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libgcrypt.so.20(GCRYPT_1.6)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I also tried this:

```
yum --disablerepo=rpmfusion-free-rawhide --enablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates install vlc-core
```

but the following errors were obtained:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libmp3lame.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libdvbpsi.so.9()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libtwolame.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgroupsock.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libdca.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libliveMedia.so.17()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libUsageEnvironment.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libmpeg2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: live555(x86-64) = 2013.11.26
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libx264.so.138()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libmad.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: liba52.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.1.5-1.fc20.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libx264.so.138()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: you are trying to install `vlc-core` from the rawhide repo. The `vlc-core` from the rawhide requires a newer libstd++ version which you don't have on your system. So I think you can use `yum --disablerepo=rpmfusion-free-rawhide install vlc-core` and see if that changes anything

Comment: yum --disablerepo=rpmfusion-free-rawhide install vlc-core
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
updates/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                             |  51 kB  00:00:00     
No package vlc-core available.

Comment: The  `rpmfusion-free-updates` repository provides the `vlc-core` package. So e.g  `yum --disablerepo=rpmfusion-free-rawhide --enablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates install vlc-core` will work. Do you have the repository in your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` path?

Comment: I updated the question with u're suggestion, still no success